# How does one Register a C# CLR Assembly with SQL Server without using Security Hacks?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security, code-signing, sqlclr

When I try and register a signed C# assembly in SQL Server via the Object Explorer in SSMS by right-clicking on the "Assemblies" node and selecting "New Assembly", then my signed DLL via "Browse", I receive the following error:

> CREATE or ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'My Assembly' with the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS option failed because the 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure is set to 1. Microsoft recommends that you sign the assembly with a certificate or asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission. Alternatively, you can trust the assembly using sp_add_trusted_assembly.

Even though I've tried signing the assembly both through a "Signing" project-properties-generated PFX file and through an sn.exe-generated SNK file (linked through hacking the project file's `AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile` node), both result in the DLL still being reported as not having a "Strong Name" by SQL Server in the "New Assembly" dialog:

[image: New Assembly Dialog]

I've tried this with both a Visual-Studio-2019-generated Class Library project in both .NET 4.8 and .NET 4.0 and a Visual-Studio-2010-generated SQL CLR Database Project all to the same end.

I understand the error message suggests a security hack to workaround the problem (which I have also tried to no avail anyway) but I'm trying to avoid these as the database server is public-facing.  How do I fix this properly?

Comment: I think you need to do `EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security', 0;
RECONFIGURE;`

Comment: That just gives me `The configuration option 'clr strict security' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.`.  Isn't that a security hack anyway?

Comment: Define "hack". What Microsoft calls "strict" security and what's actual security happen to be different things. There's a nice [article](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/) on it here. Doing this deployment "properly" is involved.

Comment: There is an explanation on GitHub here. https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/issues/25

Comment: @Steve and Matt: 1) there is no need (well, not at the moment at least) to disable "clr strict security", and 2) if that is ever needed, it is an "advanced" option, so you would need to first execute `EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; RECONFIGURE;` first (just for this option, _not_ for "clr enabled", which is _not_ an advanced option -- I know this wasn't mentioned by anyone, but it is a _very_ common misunderstanding, so I am just pre-clarifying :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the DLL truly is signed, then you are likely missing the second step of the preferred method noted in the first part of the error message, specifically:

> that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.

That part is critical to this working properly. *Prior* to loading the assembly into SQL Server, you need to do the following:

1. create an asymmetric key in the `[master]` database from the DLL
2. create a login from that asymmetric key
3. grant the new login the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` instance-level permission

*Then* you can load any assembly into any database so long as it has been signed by that same strong-name-key / pfx file (which can be several if you have multiple projects in your solution).

> Even though I've tried signing the assembly both through ..., both result in the DLL still being reported as not having a "Strong Name" by SQL Server in the "New Assembly" dialog:

Correct. This is due to either poor UI design, or a bug. When creating a new assembly, the "Additional properties:" fields do *not* reflect the values of the file indicated in the "Path to assembly:" field. Most likely this is just the "assembly" dialog for all assembly-related stuff, and it works just fine for assemblies that are already loaded into SQL Server, but not for what you are attempting to load. If the intention was to peek into the file to indicate the current values of whatever is found at the path specified in the "Path to assembly:" field, then it's a bug (but I suspect it's the former). I have reported this to Microsoft here:

[SSMS: "Additional properties" in "New Assembly" dialog is misleading as it doesn't describe DLL being imported](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39959764-ssms-additional-properties-in-new-assembly-di)

---

For info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

Comment: I was trying to run this script to register the assembly: `CREATE ASSEMBLY CryptographicFunctions
FROM 'C:\CLR Database Code\My Assembly.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE`; weirdly, it started working after running these even though it has `SAFE` as the permission set: `GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO [My Windows User Name]
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [My Windows User Name]`.  I'm now battling how to create the scalar function to point to a static method in the assembly which has now been registered (I don't know whether I can call the assembly until I've done that).

Comment: I've also just seen that if I double-click on my assembly (which now appears under the "Assemblies" node), "Strong Name" now shows as "True".

Comment: @MattArnold Prior to SQL Server 2017 introducing the insanely bad idea of "clr strict security", `SAFE` assemblies didn't require any signature, `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` could be loaded if the signature-based login had either `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` _or_ `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY`, and `UNSAFE` could be loaded only if the login had `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY`. Now, sadly, all permission set levels require `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY`. `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` is now obsolete / doesn't do anything (and even prior to 2017, `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` implied `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY`).

Comment: @MattArnold Correct, the "additional properties" in that dialog only inspect assemblies that have been loaded into SQL Server, not the DLL on the file system prior to being loaded. Is a bad UI design. I will report it to MS as it is very misleading.

Comment: @MattArnold I have updated my answer to include the link to the bug report I just field regarding those property fields not reflecting the DLL being imported. Please vote for that ticket. Thanks!

Comment: Just a couple of notes I wanted to add about creating a scalar function for a corresponding static method in the assembly:
1. `VARCHAR` does not map to `string` but `NVARCHAR` does
2. The `EXTERNAL NAME` should follow the form of: `DatabaseAssemblyReferenceName.[MyNamespace.MyStaticClass].MyStaticMethod` - I was caught out by where to put the square brackets as the `.`s outside them appear to be syntacially required to separate these 3 components.

Comment: I've just gone through this again with SQL Server 2017 instead of SQL Server 2019 (since 2019 won't allow me to debug the trigger this was all for) and I'm now back to the original error when trying to run the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` script.  I now have no idea what made this work in 2019 but I know I don't have an Asymmetric Key in the database, nor know how to add one (when I right click on the "Asymmetric Keys" node, I only get the useless option of "Start Powershell" instead of something like "Add Key..."!).

Comment: @MattArnold Doing any of this via the GUI is doing it the hard-way. All of this is rather easy to do via regular T-SQL commands. You really need to review my post here which describes exactly how to do this, and in a way that can be automated, with or without Visual Studio / SSDT: [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/). Solution 2 uses certificates only, so is a little simpler, but Solution 1 is a better integration overall.